# Can I have multiple local juju environments?

Tags: juju

Is it possible to run two local juju environments?  I sometimes like to kick off a long-running deploy, but I'd still like to work while that one is churning.

Right now, I get:

```
dpb@helo:hooks$ juju bootstrap -v
ERROR cannot use 37017 as state port, already in use
```

Do I need to run another mongodb and change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Tuned my google search enough:  https://github.com/juju/docs/issues/35

Pulled out here for reference:

```
# Alternate Local Environment
# Must be different than defaults:
#    - storage-port: 8040
#    - state-port: 37017
#    - api-port: 17071
local-alt:
    type: local
    storage-port: 8041
    state-port: 37018
    api-port: 17071
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple environments by adding a new entry into the `environments.yaml` file and then running `juju bootstrap -e myenv`.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/juju/docs/issues/35